# What are SSP in SS7

Tags: gsm, ss7

I was going through Russell's SS7 guide and was wondering what are SSP actually . Are these the telephone boxes we see on our streets or are they present inside telephone exchanges .

Answer (score 1):

According to ["Lan Tutorial With Glossary of Terms: A Complete Introduction to Local Area Networks (Lan Networking Library)" April, 1996](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0879303794):

> SS7 messages originate at an SSP [Service Switching Point], which is a telephone switch that places or receives a call. The SSP is usually found at a telco's central office, but SS7 messages may also be used by an enterprise PBX. An ISDN PRI's D channel can also send messages that are compatible with SS7.

So not the little boxes, usually.